# Question on writing to parquet in PySpark

Tags: csv, pyspark, parquet

I have encountered issues when converting csv files to parquet in PySpark. When multiple files of the same schema were converted, they don't have the same schema, because sometimes a string of number will be read as float, others as integer, etc. There also seem to be issue with the order of columns. It seems that when writing dataframes with the same columns, but arranged in different order to parquet, then these parquet cannot be loaded in the same statement.

How to write dataframes to parquet so that all columns are stored as string type? How to handle the order of columns? Shall I rearange the columns to the same order for all the dataframes before writing to parquet?

Comment: By default when you read CSV files using Spark all columns are of type string. Check you haven't enabled schema inferring (`inferSchema=True`) when reading. For the columns order, simply use `df.select(*ordered_columns_list)` before writing it to parquet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the columns and convert to string type, you can do:

```
out_df = df.select([F.col(c).cast('string') for c in sorted(df.columns)])
out_df.write.parquet(...)
```